# Merge touching faces on model

Tags: modeling, vertices

I have a model like in the following image:

[image: voxels]

There is a mesh for this object made of many individual cubic boxes. Every individual box has its own 6 faces, so where they touch with another box, there are 2 faces on the same place touching (and some of the cubes intersect each other, so their faces are inside each other).

I want to simplify this model and

- Remove internal faces (those touching each other)
- After removing faces, also remove unnecessary vertices

What's the way to do this in Blender? (using version 2.66)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to

- Join the objects into one object / mesh (select all cubes in Object Mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>)
- Enter editmode, select all <kbd>A</kbd> (if not already) and *Remove Doubles* (in <kbd>W</kbd> menu)
- Deselect all <kbd>A</kbd>
- *Select > Interior Faces*
- *Delete > Only Faces* <kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: Hi, this helped to eliminate duplicates but I still have faces between the cubes, Say, if I had originally 2 cubes, 2*6 = 12 faces, 2 of them being the same; now I have 11 faces (just removed that repeating), but I want to have only 10 (5 each cube, nothing on between) if possible remove also extra vertices (4 on the connections of the 2 boxes) such that I end up with a much simpler object. Thanks four your help! :)

Comment: If I start with 2 cubes, I end up with 10 faces after removing interior faces. Do your cubes line up perfectly? If no, try a higher threshold for *Remove Doubles*.

Comment: `W` no longer opens a menu in 2.9?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Should be _Mesh > Merge > By Distance_ or `M` in 2.8+

Answer (score 0):

CoDEmanX's answer helped me, but my situation was slightly different. I was trying to intersect a 'shaft' with a 'wall'.  The shaft's end is square.  The wall has the the same width as the shaft, but is taller.  My goal was to make the shaft join with the wall at the bottom, (so they would share the bottom, left, and right edges but not top).

I snapped the face of the shaft to the wall, and then re-snapped each vertex to make sure they were exactly on-top of eachother.  Then I used the cut tool on the wall to subdivide it horizontally.  I had to make the cut above where the shaft intersected.  Then I moved the two vertexes of the new cut down and snapped them to the top of the top two corners of the shaft.  At this point I was finally able to follow the directions of CoDEmanX (skipping the first)