# Select Interior Face, how to make it work?

Tags: modeling

I have created a cube with interior faces all over the place.
The vertices and edges have all been collasped. Running the 
Tool Select > Interior Faces ... does strange thing.

Does anyone know how this tool is suppose to work, cause it
does not seems to work as it's name implies. I have uploaded
a blend file, just in case someone could actually select those
interior faces with it.

Questions were asked [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18916/how-to-remove-interior-faces-while-keeping-exterior-faces-untouched) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32728/select-interior-faces-buggy-and-unpredictable), but they do not
show why this tool don't seem to work at all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can download the blend file which is really small in size and try it out to see for yourself, basically it select a face on the outside of the mesh rather than the inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tool is very limited. All it does is exactly in it's description:

[image]

Difference between an edge with 2 face users and edge with 3 (or more) face users:

[image]

All this tool does is for every face it checks if all it's edges have more than 2 face users. If yes, such face is selected.

This tool does not 'think' spatially and doesn't understand volumes at all. Here is an example when it will succeed and when it will fail:

[image]

Comment: @hawkenfox yes the name is unfortunate. Sadly lot of things inside blender could use additional programming so they work how you expect them to:)