# Raycast from outside a model to delete all inside faces?

Tags: mesh, unity

I'm working on a Lego project where I build models out of Lego bricks in LDD and then import them into Blender via various hoops - inside Blender I then optimize them before loading them into Unity for a small game.

The problem is that Lego has so much geometry inside a big model, because it consists of many small bricks that all have studs and at least 6 sides.

I'm thinking that there must be some kind of tool that can raycast all around outside the model and then delete/group/select all internal faces. Do any of you know of such a tool or where to find more information on this subject? Even just a more correct term would be helpful for my google ventures :)

[image: Here is an image of my model with some of the sides hidden so you can see all the abundant leftover data]

Thank you! <3

Comment: relevant https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18916/how-to-remove-interior-faces-while-keeping-exterior-faces-untouched

Comment: hmmm, I tried creating a Grid fill of boxes and then Joined them altogether. The resultant mesh approximates lots of Lego brick meshes but Selecting Internal Faces did not work and trying to Remove Doubles / Decimate removed to much geometry at least then Select Internal Faces did select internal faces but in a way that further messed up the Mesh. So YMMV

Comment: Could you provide a small sample file?  Or at least some detail re  geometry in a screenshot.

Comment: @batfinger I couldn't figure out how to attach the blender file, but I put in a screenshot where some of the faces are hidden to show all the abundant data inside.

Comment: @rob thanks - I'm also currently trying the methods in your link :)

Comment: So the "limit selection to visible" was the techinque that has worked the best so far - I rotate all around the models and select with circle select, and then invert selection and delete - but it's not deleting all the inside faces. Maybe they're too close to the outside layer, but it shouldn't be

Comment: if you exported it as an ldraw file, you could use **MeshLab** (available on Ldraw.org).  Meshlab can be used to remove the interior of a brick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick I used in 3ds max once, was to bake a tiny AO map.  Auto uvif you can.  Or maybe can vertex color as well.

But basically whatever faces were totally black, I then selected / deleted. Since we're then basically fully hidden from view.